Updating a Plotly FIgureWidget "in situ" in a Dash app
Consider the following toy Python class, which can occasionally fetch additional data from some source, and updates its display:
# minimum_working_example.py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import random

class MyData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mydata = []
        self.figure = go.FigureWidget()
        self.figure.add_trace(go.Scatter(
            name = 'mydata',
        ))
        self.get_more_data()

    def get_more_data(self):
        self.mydata += [ random.random() for _ in range(10) ]
        self.figure.update_traces(
            selector=dict(name='mydata'),
            y = self.mydata,
            x = list(range(len(self.mydata))),
        )

If I go into a Jupyter notebook and say things like
# interactive jupyter prompt
from minimum_working_example import MyData
mydata = MyData()
display(mydata.figure)

then I get a figure that I can fiddle around with: zooming the axes, toggling which traces are visible, etc.  (My non-minimal example has multiple traces.)  Because the figure is a FigureWidget, calling mydata.get_more_data() changes the trace on the graph, but it doesn't change any other feature.
[
I would like to move this display from an interactive notebook to a Dash app with a "get more data" button, but so far everything that I've tried causes the figure to reset all of its modifications, rather than updating in place.  Here's an example fails in an educational way, based on the documentation page for Partial Property Updates:
# mwe_dash.py
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output, Patch, callback
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import datetime
import random

import minimum_working_example

app = Dash(__name__)
mydata = minimum_working_example.MyData()

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Button("Append", id="append-new-val"),
        dcc.Graph(figure=mydata.figure, id="append-example-graph"),
    ]
)

@callback(
    Output("append-example-graph", "figure"),
    Input("append-new-val", "n_clicks"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def put_more_data_on_figure(n_clicks):
    mydata.get_more_data()
    return mydata.figure

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8056)

If I run this by itself with python mwe_dash.py, then the figure is completely reset every time I press the "get more data" button — just like the examples on the documentation page above.  But if I run it within Jupyter, with
# in jupyter again
from mwe_dash import app, mydata
display(mydata.figure)
app.run(jupyter_server_url='localhost:8888',port=8057)

then appearance-changing interactions with the figure in the Jupyter notebook are applied in the Dash app when the figure updates.  However, the figure in the Dash app resets to the version in the notebook every time the "get more data" button is pressed.
How can I get the figure in the Dash app to reproduce the update-without-resetting behavior that is in the Jupyter notebook?  I assume I need some additional callback from the figure to the Dash app. Will it be necessary to have a Jupyter server running in the background, even when I get rid of the notebook part of this analysis tool?


If you want "move this display from an interactive notebook to a Dash app", use a go.Figure() instead of go.FigureWidget(). 2. You are not doing partial update : fig.update_traces() updates the figure on the backend and the callback just returns it (the whole figure), so on the clientside you loose the state of the previously loaded figure. You should use the Patch class as mentioned in the documentation page you are referring to. 3. Don't create/update the figure in MyData class, just create/update the data and consume them when needed.


Thanks. I didn't explore Patch in depth yet because the "append" example on the linked documentation page --- which is the closest thing there to the behavior I want --- doesn't preserve zoom levels etc. either. Can you expand into an answer?

Note you should use extend() rather than append() (it's the same vocabulary as for python built-in lists : append is for adding one single value, extend is for adding a list of values). See full example in the answer below.


If you want to "move this display from an interactive notebook to a Dash app", use a go.Figure() instead of go.FigureWidget().

You are not doing partial update : fig.update_traces() updates the figure on the backend and the callback just returns it (the whole figure), so on the clientside you loose the state of the previously loaded figure. You should use the Patch class to extend the list of values in x and y.

Don't create/update the figure in MyData class, just create/update the data and consume them when needed (single-responsibility principle).


class MyData:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
        self.get_more_data()

    def get_more_data(self):
        newdata = [ random.random() for _ in range(10) ]
        self.data += newdata
        return newdata

app = Dash(__name__)

mydata = MyData()

y = mydata.data
x = list(range(len(y)))

fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, name='mydata'))

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Button("Append", id="append-new-val"),
        dcc.Graph(figure=fig, id="append-example-graph"),
    ]
)

@callback(
    Output("append-example-graph", "figure"),
    Input("append-new-val", "n_clicks"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def put_more_data_on_figure(n_clicks):
    i = len(mydata.data)

    new_y = mydata.get_more_data()
    new_x = list(range(i, i+len(new_y)))

    patched_figure = Patch()
    patched_figure['data'][0]['x'].extend(new_x)
    patched_figure['data'][0]['y'].extend(new_y)

    return patched_figure

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)


In my non-minimal-example code, the new data comes from a more complex analysis. The equivalent of .get_more_data() generates new vectors for each of several traces, with some existing points remaining the same, some additional points being added, and some existing points being modified — think a moving average which expands to include the new points. Pandas is involved. It looks like type(figure.data[0]['x'] is numpy.ndarray, which has neither .append() nor .extend() methods. Is that relevant? Your example (v1) has the figure doing some surgery on the data to extract the changes.

A numpy ndarray is always converted to a list in the final figure so that it can be properly JSON encoded as an array for the frontend (javascript doesn't know ndarrays), but yes the Patch methods don't take care of that so you need to use ndarray.tolist() at some point. Now, if you also have existing points being modified, the approach might be different but this sounds like another question (the answer would be different). If you are stuck, don't hesitate to ask another question with all the relevant details.

I don't get what you mean by "Your example (v1) has the figure doing some surgery on the data to extract the changes".

By "doing surgery," I mean inspecting the new data and computing the differences. If only the differences are relevant, it seems like it would make more sense for the data object to be able to return those when requested. Your offhand reminder that I need to have the Javascript data structures in mind, rather than just the Python data structures, makes these limitations a lot clearer to me. I'll ask a follow-up if I need to. Thanks for your help!
